# Cannot turn on developmen't mode in expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I was working with expo on a project for over two weeks now without any problems. Today I tried to turn of development mode in expo. Everything was fine until I tried to change back to development mode. It won't go back to development mode even if I explicitly start with `exp start --dev`.

I tried starting expo with `exp start --clear --dev` but to no avail.

I am using exp 57.0.0 on linux.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue with Expo Cli, try to install Expo XDE from [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/installation).
Then activate the Development Mode from the XDE, like this:

(check and not unchek :) )

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It didn't work at first but after multiple restarts and reloads, it worked. Yay!  I wonder what the issue is?

Comment: @NikhilMTomy I faced the same problem, and when I searched I found that it was a bug in the cli... (I do not have more infos about the bug ☹) So immediately I switched to this solution...

Comment: Note that Expo XDE has since been replaced with Expo DevTools (which is automatically opened when running `expo start` by default). Read more on the blog: https://blog.expo.io/announcing-expo-dev-tools-beta-c252cbeccb36

Comment: @JibstaMan Yes! and it works really good.. Thanks for the information